# how should I change parsing method or correct random method

Tags: go, random

I would like to generate a random 17 digits number string and parse it to uint64 by golang, here is my code:

```
const msgMaxValue      = 100000000000000000
s := fmt.Sprintf("%17v", rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())).Int63n(msgMaxValue))
log.Info("s:", s)
msgId, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
```

the error is: invalid syntax, I found there is a space in random value but don't know why, how should I fix it, thank u

Comment: Given `strconv.Atoi` returns an `int` - even if you properly generated a 17 digits long string `s` - it still would not fit an `int` type. What is the original problem you're solving?

Comment: yeah, sorry for my question mistake, I have edited it again, I wanna parse string to uint64, but it doesn't work

Comment: I have fixed it by using "crypto/rand"

Comment: just make `msgId, err := strconv.Atoi(strings.ReplaceAll(s, " ", ""))` instead. There is a space because it generates 16 digit number also and your format prints 17 letters, so there is a space sometimes on the beginning, but you can remove it and then it's parsed correctly

Comment: Pick a random digit in [1..9] and put it in a string.  Then pick 16 more digits in [0..9] and add them to the end of your string.  You don't want a leading zero.

Comment: @Vrangz  I have a question that why it generates 16 digits instead of 17 letters?

Comment: @Frank I'm not sure, but it also generates values with 15, 14 and 13 digits but these are rare. Well - `Int63n(...)` does not guarantee any number of digits. It takes random number from 0 to n, that's all. Maybe it's the matter of the seed. Anyway - you can do for loop and roll 17 times for a digit and merge them into string and then parse, the better result. But if you want an unique id - you should use uuid4 for example and not to try do it on your own, because sooner or later it will repeat with that simple algorithm

Comment: I see, thank u so much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

have fixed it by "crypto/rand", below is code:

```
func CreateRandomNumber(len int) (string, error) {
    var numbers = []byte{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9}
    var container string
    length := bytes.NewReader(numbers).Len()

    for i := 0; i < len; i++ {
        random, err := rand.Int(rand.Reader, big.NewInt(int64(length)))
        if err != nil {
            log.Error("random error:", err)
            return "", err
        }
        container += fmt.Sprintf("%d", numbers[random.Int64()])
    }
    return container, nil
}
```

then `strconv.Atoi` to get a int type number is okay